# passing multiple urls within url query params

Tags: javascript, uri

I have to handle a case where multiple urls should be passed in the url query params, for example:

```
http://example.com/?landing=<url1>&referrer=<url2>

url1: http://test1.com/test.html?param=x&param2=y
url2: http://test2.com/test/test.html?p=x&c=&...
```

At the moment I'm trying the following without success:

```
var l = encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
var r = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
window.location.href = 'http://example.net/?landing=' + l + '&ref=' + r;
```

My question is:
What would be the best way to encode url1 and url2? Should I use encodeURIComponent or would it be better to use base64 encoding for those params or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're fine with URL-encoding the whole parameters, but if you're encoding full URLs you should use `encodeURI` instead of `encodeURIComponent`.

A possible issue here is that the first and/or second URL passed as query string parameters may reach the [maximum characters allowed in an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), but as long as you can predict that this will never happen, you're still fine again!

About the base64 approach, you could reach the so-called maximum characters allowed in an URL limitation easily.